# Hotkeys in russian keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I saw many CLOSED topics about this, BUT none of proposed solutions working. When I switch to russian keyboard, shortcuts (ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl+z, etc.) not working in most of applications. I have updated system 14.04. Propose the solution, but don't just close the thread saying that everything is working! Thanks in advance for any help, because I'm realy tired of this and start to think about other Linux distros.

Comment: Give please an example of application which does not do `CTRL`+`C`or `CTRL`+`V` with switched Russian input on.

Comment: Inkscape - ctrl+z, ctrl+shift+z, ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl+o... (all shortcuts) not working; Lazarus - only ctrl+I working, others - not; VLC - all shortcuts not working... Is there any sense to continue?

Comment: Never mind, keep saying that everything works. Solved by replacing Ubuntu with another OS. Sad, but true.

Comment: I am having this problem too. Ctrl-c Ctrl-v hotkeys are not working for me when Russian keyboard layout is enabled

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
restart unity-settings-daemon
```